# Grails RestfulController doesn't respond with a JSON when Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded header is present

Tags: rest, grails, grails-2.5

I'm trying to implement a simple RestfulController for my application.
Given the following domain class:

```
class Test {
    String name
    int someInteger

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

and its controller:

```
class TestController extends RestfulController<Test>{
    TestController() {
        super(Test)
    }
}
```

Inside conf/UrlMappings.groovy I added the following entries:

```
"/api/$controller?(.${format})?" {
    action = [POST: "save", PUT: "save", GET: "index", DELETE:"error"]
}

"/api/$controller/$id?(.${format})?" {
    action = [POST: "update", PUT: "update", GET: "show", DELETE: "delete"]
}
```

Get requests are working fine, but Post and Put requests to a URL like `http://localhost:8080/app/api/test.json` when the `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` Header is present fail to respond with a JSON as expected. Instead render the show action view after persisting the entrie sent.

I also tried to use the Header `Accept: application/json` with no effect.

How can I fix that?

Edit:

Further investigating `RestfulController`'s source file and the docs section regarding [Content Negotiation](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/guide/single.html#contentNegotiation) I was able fix it by overriding the save and update methods replacing the line:

```
request.withFormat {
```

with:

```
withFormat {
```

Is it intentional or is there a flaw on `RestfulController`'s implementation?
Why does it consider the Content-Type header instead of the Accept header to render response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for taking so long to respond. I had some trouble putting everything to work. Thanks a lot @Dónal for all the help. Ended using the following class to do the trick:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

import grails.artefact.Artefact;
import grails.rest.RestfulController;
import grails.transaction.Transactional;

@Artefact("Controller")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class MyRestfulController<T> extends RestfulController<T> {

    public MyRestfulController(Class<T> resource, boolean readOnly = false) {
        super(resource, readOnly);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    def save() {
        if(handleReadOnly()) {
            return
        }
        T instance = createResource(getParametersToBind())

        instance.validate()
        if (instance.hasErrors()) {
            respond instance.errors, view:'create' // STATUS CODE 422
            return
        }

        instance.save flush:true

        def formatHolder = params.format ? this : request
        formatHolder.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: "${resourceName}.label".toString(), default: resourceClassName), instance.id])
                redirect instance
            }
            '*' {
                response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.LOCATION,
                        g.createLink(
                                resource: this.controllerName, action: 'show',id: instance.id, absolute: true,
                                namespace: hasProperty('namespace') ? this.namespace : null ))
                respond instance, [status: HttpStatus.CREATED]
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    def update() {
        if(handleReadOnly()) {
            return
        }

        T instance = queryForResource(params.id)
        if (instance == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        instance.properties = getParametersToBind()

        if (instance.hasErrors()) {
            respond instance.errors, view:'edit' // STATUS CODE 422
            return
        }

        instance.save flush:true

        def formatHolder = params.format ? this : request
        formatHolder.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: "${resourceClassName}.label".toString(), default: resourceClassName), instance.id])
                redirect instance
            }
            '*'{
                response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.LOCATION,
                        g.createLink(
                                resource: this.controllerName, action: 'show',id: instance.id, absolute: true,
                                namespace: hasProperty('namespace') ? this.namespace : null ))
                respond instance, [status: HttpStatus.OK]
            }
        }
    }

}
```

By using `def formatHolder = params.format ? this : request` and then call `formatHolder.withFormat` I am now able to override the response format independently from the request format.

It doesn't work for the Accept Header yet but at least it works.

Answer (score 2):

If it's acceptable for all your controller's methods to always respond with JSON (when there a response body), you can achieve this with [responseFormats](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/responseFormats.html) like so:

```
class TestController extends RestfulController<Test>{

    static responseFormats = ['json']

    TestController() {
        super(Test)
    }

    def customJsonAction() {
        respond Something.get(params.id)
    }

    def someActionThatRendersGsp() {
        render view: 'myGsp', model: [foo: 'bar']
    }
}
```

This means the controller will always respond with JSON regardless of which headers, params, etc. are sent by the client.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, this same controller is used for a rest API and for rendering crud views. Maybe it was a bad project strategy, but the effort to change it is too big now. My workaround for now is to create a `MyRestfullController` class extending `RestfullController` changing the behavior of the save and update methods to consider the Accept Header instead of the Content-Type one.

Comment: I think my proposal should work even if there are methods that render GSP views as long as those methods call `render` instead of `respond`

Comment: So, you propose overriding those actions to use `render` inside `withFormat` blocks instead of `respond`? I'll try that and reply soon if it works. Thanks

Comment: @ylima I've updated my code sample to show what I'm proposing. There's no need to use `withFormat` unless you have different response types being rendered by the same action, which AFAIK, you don't

Comment: That would work but also require two different actions for just saving a new instance. I'm trying to figure out some way to check if the response format is set before checking the request format to render a view